# Capture Access Token from URL Azure AD to use for Token

Tags: c#, azure, razor, blazor, identity

If I send my user to the authorize endpoint, they'll get back a URL that's redirected to the URI I specify, which contains the access_code needed for the bearer token request.

Using razor pages, how is it possible to capture that access code in the URL in the code? Is the redirect page supposed to 'catch' it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token)

> There are two steps to acquire an **Azure AD access token** using the
> authorization code flow.
>
> 1. Obtain the authorization code, which launches a browser window and ask for user login. The authorization code is returned after the user
>    successfully logs in.
> 2. Use the authorization code to acquire the access token.

For more information please refer to this documentation  [LOGIN AND USE AN ASP. NET CORE API WITH AZURE AD AUTH AND USER ACCESS TOKENS](https://damienbod.com/2020/05/29/login-and-use-asp-net-core-api-with-azure-ad-auth-and-user-access-tokens/)